# Ada "Compilation Unit Expected" error

Tags: compilation, ada

I'm trying to declare a new type so I can pass an array as an argument to a procedure.  It looks like this:

```
type Arr_Type is array(1..1000) of String;

procedure proceed(Arg1: in Arr_Type) is
begin
<program body>
end
```

Whenever I try and compile this, I receive a "compilation unit expected" error.  If I remove the type declaration, I no longer get the error, but I obviously need it and I get an error if I put it anywhere else in the file.  I'm a little new to Ada so I'm not entirely sure what's happening here.

Answer (score 9):

A program in Ada has to be divided into compilation unit (procedure, function or package). The type declaration has to be contained in a unit so you could wrap these in a procedure:

```
procedure Main is

  type Arr_Type is array(1..1000) of String;

  procedure proceed(Arg1: in Arr_Type) is
  begin
   <program body>
  end proceed;

begin

   call to proceed

end Main;
```

If you already have a program calling `proceed` but want it on a separate file, you'll need a package instead. Then you create two files - a specification file (.ads) and a body file (.adb):

my_package.ads:

```
package My_Package is
  type Arr_Type is array(1..1000) of String;

  procedure proceed(Arg1: in Arr_Type);
end My_Package;
```

my_package.adb:

```
package body My_Package is

  procedure proceed(Arg1: in Arr_Type) is
  begin
   <program body>
  end Proceed;

end My_Package;
```

Then you can include this package as usual with `with My_Package` (and possible `use`)

Comment: Strictly speaking, "one compilation unit per file" is a GNAT limitation.  The important point is that what you pass to an Ada compiler has to be structured as compilation units.  See section 10.1.1 in the LRM for a definition: http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-10-1-1.html

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen, Ok I was a bit unsure about that part. Better now?